# why this don't render it self when it changes username. got from firebase in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

when a User SignUP, in the Header I want to display his name, But it shows null, When I refresh the page it shows the correct name. why this is not auto rendering on changing username.

### homepage.js

```
const [username, setusername] = useState('loading..')
 
    useEffect(() => {
       setusername(auth.currentUser.displayName);
    }, [[auth.currentUser.displayName]])
     // Some more work here
     return(
// display Name
)
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you tell it to only run `useEffect` once when you pass in an empty array, second, you can't assign to username directly, you need to use the `setusername` function.   You probably just need to do

```
useEffect(() => {
   setusername(auth.currentUser.displayName);
}, [auth.currentUser.displayName])
```

Comment: I missed typed that direct assignment of username.  but even this isn't working. I'm facing a problem when user Signed In

Comment: If this doesn't work I'd look at [this questions answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59977856/firebase-listener-with-react-hooks)