# React custom hook to set user with firebase

Tags: reactjs, firebase, next.js

I am creating a custom hook in a react application that makes use of Firebase to auth and create a user `document` in the `users` `collection`. The hook checks if a user is logged in and then checks if the `document` in the `users` `collection` for that user exists. If the `document` does not exist, one is created, if the `document` exists I create a `onSnapshot` function to check for changes in the document. My problem is setting the `username` with `useState` when a new `document` is created. Can someone please assist. I am using Firebase V9.

Here is my hook:

```js
import { auth, firestore } from './firebase-config';
import {
  doc,
  collection,
  getDoc,
  setDoc,
  onSnapshot,
} from '@firebase/firestore';
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { useAuthState } from 'react-firebase-hooks/auth';

// Custom hook to read  auth record and user profile doc
export function useUserData() {
  const [user] = useAuthState(auth);
  const [username, setUsername] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    let unsubscribe;

    if (user) {
      const documentRef = doc(firestore, 'users', user.uid);

      const getUserData = async () => {
        const docSnap = await getDoc(documentRef);
        if (docSnap.exists()) {
          unsubscribe = onSnapshot(documentRef, (doc) => {
            setUsername(doc.data().username);
          });
        } else {
          await setDoc(doc(firestore, 'users', user.uid), {
            name: user.displayName,
            email: user.email,
            username: user.displayName,
          });
          setUsername(docSnap.data().username);
        }
      };
      getUserData();
    } else {
      setUsername(null);
    }

    return unsubscribe;
  }, [user]);

  return { user, username };
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Firebase listener with React Hooks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59977856/firebase-listener-with-react-hooks)

Comment: Not really. But thanks 